# Signature for CloudFront Signed URL differs when using openssl sha1 -sign and PHP's openssl_sign

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, openssl, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to create a signed URL for an S3 bucket served by CloudFront, and am following [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-linux-openssl.html) to do it with linux OpenSSL. The following is ripped nearly directly from the example:

```
  local -r signature=$(
    openssl sha1 -sign "files/pk-${key_pair_id}.pem" policy.json \
    | openssl base64 -A \
    | tr -- '+=/' '-_~'
  )
```

The signature that this computes does not match the signature computed by the [PHP example code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreateURL_PHP.html), which supposedly is identical.

```
function rsa_sha1_sign($policy, $private_key_filename) {
    $signature = "";

    // load the private key
    $fp = fopen($private_key_filename, "r");
    $priv_key = fread($fp, 8192);
    fclose($fp);
    $pkeyid = openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key);

    // compute signature
    openssl_sign($policy, $signature, $pkeyid);

    // free the key from memory
    openssl_free_key($pkeyid);

    return $signature;
}

function url_safe_base64_encode($value) {
    $encoded = base64_encode($value);
    // replace unsafe characters +, = and / with 
    // the safe characters -, _ and ~
    return str_replace(
        array('+', '=', '/'),
        array('-', '_', '~'),
        $encoded);
}

$key_pair_id = "A...X";
$private_key_filename = "files/A...X.pem"
$signature = rsa_sha1_sign($policy, $private_key_filename);
$signature = url_safe_base64_encode($signature);
```

Assume `$policy` contains valid JSON, which matches identically with the content of `policy.json` file used in the bash example.

The PHP example computes a valid signature, which I can confirm can be used to create a valid signed URL to access the restricted content with.

Comment: When `policy` contains `{"key": "value"}`, the bash and the php appear to produce matching signatures for me.

Comment: Yikes. This might be an issue with mismatching input, but I opened this up because testing byte-for-byte identical input was producing mismatching signatures. I'll try again!

Comment: Hi @MikePatrick, you are right! These two code snippets compute identical signatures for matching input. My discrepancy was a newline at the end of the JSON input. Thanks for your help! I'm not sure if you should submit an answer for me to accept, to close/delete the question, or to answer it myself?

Comment: Happy to help!  I'd say you really answered this one yourself, so go ahead and answer/close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mike pointed out, the snippet of Bash and PHP compute identical signatures for matching input.

The discrepancy in my testing was a result of one input containing a newline at the end of the JSON input, whereas one did not. When the inputs were truly byte-for-byte identical, the snippets produce matching signatures.